# Display div while page loads (all JS and HTML/CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, jquery-masonry

I have a load of images being pulled from Wordpress attachments and then dumped on the page using a masonry grid of sorts - all good. However, it takes a little long.

Is there any way to display a div, with some text, as the page is loading, and then display: none, after?

I have this so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showContent(){
//hide loading status...
document.getElementById("loading-grid-page").style.display='none';

//show content
document.getElementById("content").style.display='block';
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="showContent()">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<div id="loading-grid-page">Fetching ALL the gold...</div>');
</script>
<div id="content">
<script type="text/javascript">
//hide content
document.getElementById("content").style.display='none';
</script>
```

and my CSS,

```
#loading-grid-page {
color: #ffffff;
font: 700 11px/25px 'proxima-nova-1', 'proxima-nova-2', sans-serif;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
background: #111111 url('images/ajax-loader-black.gif') no-repeat 15px center;
border-radius: 2px;
border: 1px solid #111111;
padding: 5px 30px;
text-align: center;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -100px;
z-index: 1000000;
}
```

However it throws back mixed results, sometimes it waits and all the masonry works, and sometimes it doesn't and the masonry fails and the page loads strangely.

Just wondered if there was anything else out there ;)

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:

1. Load an empty page and display a loader.

   first time when you load the method just load (y) images, per example 12 will be enough. Don't load all of them.
2. Use (JQuery) Ajax to load the content. 

    Use ajax/json to connect to the server and count the number of images left( total - displayed). if (total > 0) then return links to those images as a json array.

   link to jquery's [json call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). 
   link to [parsing json using PHP](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php).
3. Hide the loader.

   [Hide the div that contain the loader and add the links to the content div.](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
4. Display the content.

   Here you have two options append a div, or use an existing one but this depends on the way you implemented the code, again I recommend JQuery.

Comment: Hmm, any further help on this would be great ;) You can see the idea working here: http://goo.gl/jYMo9 - but you will also see it fail! Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I can't see your code so I am not going to write any code but I am going to try to give you some examples from the web.

Answer (score 2):

This is one great use for JQuery, if you want code to run when the page is loaded, do this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //hide loader div here
    $("#loading-grid-page").hide();
});
```

Comment: I need for the content only appear when the page is fully loaded, and for the #loading-grid-page to display while it loads. You can see my attempt here: http://goo.gl/jYMo9 - thanks for your help :)

Comment: then set the content's visibility to collapse, and in the load function set it to visibile with:
$("#content").css("visibility", "visible");

Comment: do not use display: none, as on some browsers, it will not load the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ded's [domready](https://github.com/ded/domready) event to hide the overlay when the DOM is ready.

Comment: Hiding the overlay is fine, it's really the act of hiding the whole content except the overlay until the content is ready then displaying it.

Comment: No problem, then hide the content and display it on domready.

Comment: But if JS is disabled, no content will load? Or do you mean, hide it with JS as well?

Comment: It's not clear how your page is set up. If you have jQuery, and if your content is dynamically loaded, then it won't work without JS anyway. In this case, you should just use something like imagesLoaded and jQuery's standard .ready event. If your content is not dynamically loaded, then you should use .ready alone to show the content, and hide it with jQuery immediately on load.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a Div Like below below body tag
2. Include Ext Js library on head as script
3. creat a script tag and write down below lines within script tag

   var Mask;
   function loadMask(el,flag,msg){
       Mask= new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.get(el), {msg:msg});
       if(flag)
           Mask.show();
       else
           Mask.hide();
   }
4. call function beforeload on body tag and call your function loadMask as below
   javascript:loadMask('myLoading',true,'Loading ...')
5. call function onload on body tag and call javascript:loadMask('myLoading',false,'Loading ...')

if step 4 not working then create a new function unloadMask and within this function write below code and call this function on onload of body tag

```
function unloadMask(){ 
 Ext.util.CSS.createStyleSheet(".myloadingjs {\n visibility:hidden;  \n } ", "GoodParts");
}
```